# .htaccess allow domain.com/sub to be browsed to, but also make somethingelse.domain.com go to that same folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm in need of assistance with mod_rewrite. Currently, I've a folder at www.domain.com/folder. I need to leave the files where they are, but have the address bar in the browser appear as someothername.domain.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I should mention that I've already got a few .htaccess rules in place, as shown here:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance,
-Ray

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 .htaccess like this:

`DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

`/folder/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks!  The question is then this, and I'm afraid I wasn't as clear as I'd intended in the original post.  If they browse to domain.com/folder, that's great, I want the URL to show that.  If they browse to subdomain.domain.com I want *that* to show in the address bar but still have them actually be going to domain.com/folder.  Will your solution do the trick?

Comment: What is `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `subdomain.domain.com`?

Comment: document root of the subdomain will be domain.com/subdomain

Comment: But then aren't `domain.com/folder` same as  `sub.domain.com/`